# Direct Memory Access (DMA) Scheduling in a Multithreaded Application

Tags: network-programming, io, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

I would like to use DMA to accelarate network I/O (intensive disk reads and output via Internet). I wonder if I have a multithreaded application where each thread issues DMA transfers how does the disk I/O and DMA transfers are scheduled by the OS?

As far as I understand, the kernel loads the required portion of data to RAM from disk without user program and issues DMA transfer. Hence, a disk scheduler will not help a lot (only a single kernel process always accesses the disk). Also may I hope that there are any in-kernel facilities to schedule DMA transfers when for the data that was loaded into memory?

Comment: DMA transfers are made by hardware not by applications. The main idea about DMA is not spending processor time with the transfer, so the device like disk or network card can write/read directly from/to memory without taking CPU time. The Kernel itself is not responsible for the DMA transfer, it only ask for the transfer to be done and do other stuff until the request is completed. Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access

Comment: @peter thank you, I have posted a comment below to clarify the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The network driver will already be using DMA to accelerate to transfers. When you issue a `write` the kernel will allocate a contiguous block of physical memory and copy the data from your userspace buffer into this memory. During this phase the kernel will attach all the necessary Ethernet and TCP/IP headers.

The kernel will then issue a DMA request to the network card, asking it to take data from that physical memory location and load it into its internal buffers. At this point your `write` system call will return. When the network card is complete (and the data is on its way out of the adapter) the network card will signal completion to the kernel.

In Linux network drivers are normally single threaded (there are some exceptions to this but it gets complicated), so if you try to `write` some data and the driver is already active it will still be copied into kernel space but the DMA request will not be performed until the network driver is free again (it'll be triggered when the kernel is next notified that a DMA is complete).

The morale of the story is that this already works and is rather fast, there's nothing you need to do to accelerate and application using DMA, it's already been taken care of. The only piece you could speed up would be the copy in the kernel space buffer, but as this is so much quicker than the actual network transfer (and can be done simultaneously) it doesn't make any difference to throughput, only latency.

N.B. The above is a gross simplification in places, if you want more detail about a specific part edit your question and I'll do what I can.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I haven't nocited it until this time since Stackoverflow did not send me a corresponding e-mail. To clarify my question: if two threads of the same process (an application) or two different processes request DMA, will it be concurrent or they will interfere each other. My question arises from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-zerocopy/ where a programmer should take care of DMA and it is not done by default.

Comment: A single disk or a single network adapter can only do one thing at a time, so they'll happen serially. But you can submit both requests in parallel (issue two write() calls at the same time and have them return) and the kernel will schedule them in the background (using one at most one core per disk and one core per network card).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a description on the Web or this is your own experience?

Comment: It's my own experience. It's difficult to find explanations for this kind of thing on the internet, most people will point you to the code. You can read about modern attempts to make NIC/disk handling multithreaded ([NIC](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/scaling.txt), [disk](http://lwn.net/Articles/552904/))